# Complications with auto commit switch

Tags: java, mysql, string

When I run my code, I just keep getting the error:

> "ResultSet not open. Verify that autocommit is OFF."

How can I fix it?

I can't get it to work. I'm sure it has to do with `con.setAutoCommint(false);` or executeQuery.

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeString.split;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class Database_console {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/English Words";
        try {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/English Words";
            String uName = "User";
            String uPass= "password";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            String SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM ENGLISH_1";
            String SQL2 = "SELECT * FROM ENGLISH_2";
            String SQL3 = "SELECT * FROM ENGLISH_3";
            String SQL4 = "SELECT * FROM ENGLISH_4";
            String SQL5 = "SELECT * FROM ENGLISH_5";

            ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery( SQL1);
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery( SQL2);
            ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery( SQL3);
            ResultSet rs4 = stmt.executeQuery( SQL4);
            ResultSet rs5 = stmt.executeQuery( SQL5);

            while(rs1.next()) {
                String 1 = rs1.getString("1");
                String 2 = rs2.getString("2");
                String 3 = rs3.getString("3");
                String 4 = rs4.getString("4");
                String 5 = rs5.getString("5");
                con.commit();
                System.out.println( 1 + " " + 2 + " " + 3 " " + 4 " " 5 + " ");
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix indentation, make code compilable, and post stack trace. Sure you want to name your variables "1", "2", etc.? Also, there seems to be hardly anything to commit since there are only SELECTs. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking about an error, it's best to try to identify the source code line from which the error came in your question.

Comment: Why are you committing?

Answer (score 0):

Two things: First, COMMIT closes out transactions that start with BEGIN TRANSACTION. You don't have any of those.

Second, When you're using JDBC to execute SELECT statements, you need to execute each SQL statement, then retrieve and close its result set, before starting the next one. The code you showed tries to create a bunch of ResultSet objects and then read them one by one. You Can't Do That.™

Important: Don't forget to close() each ResultSet when you're done with it. ResultSets can be scarce resources on your database servers.

For example, try this.

```
String SQL1 = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ENGLISH_1";
String SQL2 = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ENGLISH_2";

Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );

ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery( SQL1 );
while(rs1.next()) {
  String s1 = rs1.getString(1);
  String s2 = rs1.getString(2);
  String s3 = rs1.getString(3);
  System.out.println( s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
}
rs1.close();

ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery( SQL2 );
while(rs2.next()) {
  String t1 = rs2.getString(1);
  String t2 = rs2.getString(2);
  String t3 = rs2.getString(3);
  System.out.println( t1 + " " + t2 + " " + t3);
}
rs2.close();
```